# SKlearn Tfidfvectorizer with Keras: expected dense_input_1 to have shape

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I'm trying to combine SKLearn Tfidfvectorizer with Keras but I'm stuck at the following error: 
Exception: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_1 to have shape (None, 126) but got array with shape (700, 116)

I understand it has something to do with the shape of the matrix but I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=self.identity, use_idf=True, max_features=2000)

#a list of sentences
x_train_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train).toarray()
x_test_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(self.x_test[i]).toarray()

#labels
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, self.nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, self.nb_classes)

#get model
model = self.build_model(x_train_vec.shape[1])
model.fit(x_train_vec, y_train, nb_epoch=self.n_epochs, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle='batch', verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test_vec, y_test), )
```

Build model:

```
def build_model(self, nb_features):
    print("Building model...")

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_dim = nb_features, output_dim = self.hidden_units_1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

Comment: Your dimensions clearly don't match, what are the shapes of x_train_vec, x_test_vec, and the input_dim to the first Dense layer?

Comment: x_train_vec.shape = (2000, 126), x_test_vec.shape = (700, 116). The input_dim is currently defined as x_train_vec.shape[1]

Comment: I see the problem, Dense takes fixed dimension data, your train data has 2000 dimensions, while the test data has 700 dimensions. This won't work.

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the difference in dimensions in x_train and x_test. Changing the max features in the tfidfvectorizer solved the problem.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=self.identity, use_idf=True, max_features=100)
```

Comment: This is wrong. @gat gets it right. It will not crash, but it is scientifically incorrect. You use data from the tests within your training like this.

Answer (score 3):

When you vectorize your test set, you need to call `transform` and not `fit_transform`:

```
x_train_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train).toarray()
x_test_vec = vectorizer.transform(self.x_test[i]).toarray()
```